# Error with << operator overload returning a std::string

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, iostream

I'm having troubles understanding the reason why the compiler accuses error, when the return type of a `<<` operator overload is `std::string`. Could you please help me understand?

Bellow is an reproducible example, which gives a gigantic error.

```
class XY
{
    int X__;
    int Y__;
 public:
    XY(int x, int y):X__(x), Y__(y){}
    ~XY(){}

    std::string operator<<(const XY_cartesiano& c)
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "{ " << X__ << ", " << Y__ << " }";
        return ss.str();
    }

    int x() const{return X__;}
    int y() const{return Y__;}
};

void main()
{

XY a(1,2);
std::cout << a;
}
```

Comment: This isn’t the problem, but names that contain two consecutive underscores (`X__`, `Y__`) and names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for use by the implementation. Don’t use them in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take something like this as an example:

```
cout << "My number is " << 137 << " and I like it a lot." << endl;
```

This gets parsed as

```
((((cout << "My number is ") << 137) << " and I like it a lot.") << endl);
```

In particular, notice that the expression `cout << "My number is "` has to evaluate to something so that when we then try inserting 137 with `<< 137` the meaning is "take 137 and send it to `cout`."

Imagine if `cout << "My number is "` were to return a `string`. In that case, the `<< 137` bit would try to use the `<<` operator between a `string` on the left-hand side and an `int` on the right-hand side, which isn't well-defined in C++.

The convention is to have the stream insertion operator `operator <<` return a reference to whatever the left-hand side stream is so that these operations chain well. That way, the thing on the left-hand side of `<< 137` ends up being `cout` itself, so the above code ends up essentially being a series of chained calls to insert things into `cout`. The signature of these functions therefore usually look like this:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const ObjectType& myObject) {
     // ... do something to insert myObject into out ... //
     return out;
}
```

Now, everything chains properly. Notice that this function is a free function, not a member function, and that the left-hand side is of type `ostream` and the right-hand side has the type of your class in it. This is the conventional way to do this, since if you try overloading `operator <<` as a member function, the left-hand side will be an operand of your class type, which is backwards from how stream insertion is supposed to work. If you need to specifically access private fields of your class in the course of implementing this function, make it a friend:

```
class XY {
public:
      ...
      friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const XY& myXY);
};

ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const XY &myXY) {
    ...
    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct way to overload `<<` operator in your case is

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const XY& c)  
{  
    os << c.X__ <<" "<< c.Y__ ;
    return os;  
}
```

Comment: It's actually probably best to use an internal `ostringstream` to build an entire string that gets printed at once in case `os` has its width modifier set (or other transient stream modifiers) so that the output doesn't get partially mangled.

Answer (score 1):

You have overloaded `operator<<` in a way that's incompatible with the conventions you must follow when you intend to use the operator with a `std::ostream` object like `std::cout`.

In fact, your `operator<<`'s signature has nothing to do with streams at all!  It is just a member function of `XY` which takes another `XY` (which it then does not use), returns a string and has an unsual name. Here's how you would theoretically call it:

```
XY a(1,2);
XY b(1,2);
std::string x = (a << b);
```

The correct way to overload `operator<<` for use with streams is to make the operator a non-member function, add a stream reference parameter and return a stream reference to the stream argument. You also do not need a string stream; you write directly to the stream you get:

```
#include <iostream>

class XY
{
    int x;
    int y;
public:
    XY(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}

    int X() const { return x; }
    int Y() const { return y; }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, XY const& c)
{
    os << "{ " << c.X() << ", " << c.Y() << " }";
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    XY a(1,2);
    std::cout << a;
}
```